# How to do an operation with keyup or input? javascript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I got a problem, I have two text fields, both have a value by default when open the page or reaload, values the I get from MySQL and PHP, like this:

```
<input type="text" id="field1" value="<?php echo $first_value; ?>" />
<input type="text" id="utility" value="<?php echo $second_value; ?>" />
```

And with javascript I would like to do that when I change the value of `#field1` do a subtraction and show the result into `#utility`.

The problem is that the result of the operation isn't correct, for example:

if `#field1` has 500 the first time and `#utility` 1041.00 and now if I change the value of `#field1` with 1000 the new value for `#utility` is -69.06, I guess it is doing the operation everytime that I delete or add a new number but I have no idea how to fix this, this is my javascript (jquery) code:

```
 $('#field1').on('input', function() {

   var difference = parseFloat($(this).val());
   var utility   = $('#utility').val().replace(/,/g, '');


   var total = utility - difference;

   if (!total) { total = 0; }

   $('#utility').val(parseFloat(Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
});
```

Comment: `do a rest` (Representational state transfer ) Do you mean do an Ajax call to the PHP server?

Comment: `The problem is that the result of the operation isn't correct, for example:` How isn't it correct?  What should it look like corrected? What's the `operation`? You need to tell us what you're trying to do

Comment: @Kisaragi I'm trying to do a rest with those values and see the results immediately, but the value by default of `#utilty` should be immutable for every time that I want to do the operation, always should be the value of the php variable and see how it is changing, sorry I'm trying to explain it the best I can do, my english is not very good

Comment: Huh? Still not clear. Remember the php value is set at the server, and sent to the client. The JS code only affects the client, unless there is an ajax call (my question above, which you've not answered yet.)In simple words what are you trying to do?

Comment: @zipzit just a rest and display the results in real-time

Comment: what do you mean by _" a rest "_ ?

Comment: @CodeGodie a subtraction

Comment: I'm not understanding your use of the word `rest`.  To `rest` could mean take a break, I'm tired. (insert a 30 second pause in the functioning of the code.)  That doesn't make sense. To others, a 'rest' is an abbreviation for  REpresentational State Transfer.  The word doesn't really fit here, but a REStful API refers to a call back to the server to send and receive information.    I call a round trip to the server without a web page refresh an AJAX call ("Asynchronous Javascript and XML")  Do you mean AJAX call?

Comment: ok. So what is your answer suppose to be? is it `1000 - 1041.00 = -41`? What is the wrong answer, and what is the right answer? Please provide details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating a new input field type `hidden` with the same value of `#utility` and I named it as `#new_utilty`

```
 $('#field1').on('input', function() {

   var difference = parseFloat($(this).val());
   var utility   = $('#new_utility').val().replace(/,/g, '');


   var total = utility - difference;

   if (!total) { 

      total = 0; 
      $('#utility').val(parseFloat(Math.round(utility * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));

   } else {

       $('#utility').val(parseFloat(Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
   }
});
```

And this was my solution without Ajax Call

Answer (score 1):

Your other option without adding extra fields would be to use `.on('blur',function(){} )` or simply `.blur(function(){})`

This would cause the action to take place when input left the field forcing the refresh.